# sql database interaction from visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008, asp.net-4.0

I have a helper class in my root `AppCode` folder that saves me time and coding executing database related tasks

and i am looking for a way to have all tables and columns names into the intelliSense

so for example

```
public static class GetTableData
{
    //base method
    static int ExecSQLint(string TblintSQL)
    {
        int value;
        SqlConnection myConn = new SqlConnection("server=(local);Initial Catalog=dbName;Integrated Security=True");
        SqlCommand TblintCMD = new SqlCommand(TblintSQL, myConn);

        try
        {
            myConn.Open();
            value = Convert.ToInt32(TblintCMD.ExecuteScalar());
        }
        finally
        {
            myConn.Close();
        }

        return value;
    }

    //return a Database value as int 
    public static int AsInt(string FieldToSearch, string tblName, string WhereClause, string FLdValue)
    {
        string TblintSQL = "SELECT " + FieldToSearch + " FROM " + tblName + " WHERE " + WhereClause + " ='" + FLdValue + "'";
        return ExecSQLint(TblintSQL);
    }
}
```

so if i need a customer id(int) from  a table for example

some `[tblCustomers]` i have a column named `custID` and `name`

i will retrive customer id via following Code

```
int custId = GetTableData.AsInt("custID", "tblCustomers", "name", "warren");
```

I would like to get available Columns and table names into Visual studio so i will not have to use
strings as used in example above 
what would be the simplest way to achieve that ?,

is it by generating  a code that will generate a  class with `const strings`

or is there a utility I don't know about inside the Visual Studio ? (I'm currently using 2010 Pro)

Comment: Data layers are well defined by the code itself, and therefore are a perfect candidate to be generated. Hence see AntLaC's answer.

Comment: @miguel , could you give me a little head start , msdn is really hard for me to comprehend

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Entity Framework to build classes from your tables, views and stored procedures.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386876(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: because i could not really understand where and how to start after checking msdn link ...I did try something with codesmith.. that does the  work for me ..though  didn't like the idea that  there's a better way with `.net FrameWork` . could you please be a little more specific with the native / .net - entity way please ?